# Acessar function declarada na controller da directive pelos objetos transclude

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directives

Estou tentando criar uma directive que tem seu scope isolado, mas que tenha algumas funções que ela estará responsável de fazer p/ directive. É uma div que contém uma table e um botão "Adicionar" ao clicar no adicionar abrirá abaixo da table um tipo formulário pra alimentar aquela table. Usei transclude p/ este formulário e gostaria de ao clicar em um determinado button (incluso no transclude) venha executar as functions que determinei na directive p/ copiar os registros pra table de forma dinamica, para que não venha a cada controller que usar esta diretiva tenho que fazer tudo na mão esta funcionalidade. Segue os códigos abaixo:

**HTML Directive**:

```html
<div class="form-horizontal panel panel-default panel-group">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div  ui-grid="options" class="grid" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer" style="margin-top: -25px;">
        <div style="text-align: right;">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#divForm{{idGrid}}">Adicionar</button>
        </div>
        <div id="divForm{{idGrid}}" class="collapse">
            <br>
            <ng-transclude></ng-transclude>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**grid-form.directive.js** :

```js
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('controlwebApp')
        .directive('gridForm', gridForm);

    function gridForm () {
        var directive = {
            restrict: 'E',
            transclude: true,
            scope: {
                options: '=',
                idGrid: "@idGrid"
            },
            templateUrl: 'app/components/grid/gridform/grid-form.directive.html',
            bindToController: {
                teste: '&'
            },
            controller: function (){
                this.teste = function(){
                    console.log("Teste Calling!!")
                }
            },
            controllerAs: 'ctrl'
        };

        return directive;
    }

})();
```

**Uso da directiva**:

```
 <div class="form-group">
        <grid-form id-grid="grid1" options="vm.gridOptions">
            <div class="form-horizontal">
                <label class="control-label" for="field_qtdEstoqueMax">Qtd Estoque Max1</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="qtdEstoqueMax" id="field_qtdEstoqueMax" ng-model="vm.produto.qtdEstoqueMax" />
                <label class="control-label" for="field_qtdEstoqueMax">Qtd Estoque Max2</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="qtdEstoqueMax" id="field_qtdEstoqueMax" ng-model="vm.produto.qtdEstoqueMax"/>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ctrl.teste()">Save me</button>
            </div>
        </grid-form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode criar um objeto para servir de ponte entre os escopos do *controller* e da *directive*; O conteúdo transportado terá assim acesso aos métodos implementados pela diretiva.

Exemplo funcional abaixo:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.directive('transcludeableDirective', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      bridgeObject: "="
    },
    templateUrl: 'myTranscludeTemplate',
    transclude: true,
    controller: function($scope) {

      // Diretiva implementa evento event()
      $scope.bridgeObject.event = function(){
        alert('Evento da diretiva chamado!');
      };
    },
  };
})
.controller('myController', function($scope){
  $scope.bridge = {}; // Note que o controller não implementa o método.
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller='myController'>
    <div transcludeable-directive bridge-object='bridge'>
      TESTE
      <button ng-click='bridge.event()'>CLICK!</button>
    </div>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myTranscludeTemplate">
      <h2><div ng-transclude></div></h2>
    </script>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfeita estrategia brother, funcionou corretamente. Obrigado, infelizmente não tenho pontos ainda suficiente pra dar +1 na sua resposta =(      Tive um probleminha na minha controller da directiva, um erro(https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/strictdi) que já consta na doc. do angular a correção pra Controller normais, resolvi assim:  controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
          $scope.gridBindObject.onteste = function(){
           alert("Funcionou");
          }
         }]

Comment: @RaulMarques Nem estressa com isso, fico feliz que tenha funcionado. Se for o caso, marque como resposta aceita se seu problema tiver sido resolvido. =)